# Remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key

Tags: ios, app-store, uibackgroundmode

I submitted my app on Appstore but it got reject because the background audio was enabled, I resubmitted the App this time I removed the 'Required background modes' key form the .plist file as well as disabled the 'Background Modes' from under Capabilities, but again the app was rejected and on query App Store Review gave me this response:

> After further review background audio is still enabled. Please remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.
>
> Once this issue has been addressed we can proceed with review.

Screen shot of .plist file:[image]
Screen shot of Background Mode under Capabilities: [image]

Some help would be appreciated to get my app approved.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is remove the items under "Required Background Modes". You will find this setting in your `[appname]-info.plist` file which is located in your resources folder.

[image]